# OAuth2 - Safety of permanent access to my account

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token

I would like to allow users downloading files on my site, but some will require certain number of points. I am using small hosting, so they are stored on my Google Drive account with the purchased additional space.

I set access_type to 'offline' and I'm using refresh token to renew access token, if it expire. The main problem is that, console shows requests which contain token.

I want know, could users use access_token to gain access to file, though they don't have enough points? What is the best way to hide requests?

Comment: Which "console" are you referring to? If it is the Javascript console of the browser, how would that be a problem since it is the user that has enough points who is able to access that console, assuming you don't issue access tokens to users who don't have enough points.

Comment: Yes, I mean browser's console. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880489/oauth2-is-it-safe-to-return-the-access-token-to-the-user I shouldn't reveal access token. What if user has permission to download file, but doesn't have to another one? He would know token, but could he use it to download another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I think I get your issue; actually the access token should have rights associated with it that only allow it to download a specific file on behalf of you, but I don't think that granularity is possible with Google's access tokens; so what you must do is implement your own system on top of that in your service, allowing for that granularity

so you would keep the access token in your backend service only, and have the Javascript client call in to your backend service for specific files, then check in your backend service whether the user is allowed or not and if allowed pass on the request to Google

edit: this is described here: http://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

Comment: Sorry, but I mean something completly different. While authentication, you can see request to Google's server, which contain access_token in parameters. If user would have enought point then he will know token. According to question about safety of revealing it to user, i want know, could he use it outside my site to get access to files?

Comment: you can use a flow that does not expose the access token in the front channel, the so-called "code" flow; in this flow a "code" parameter is returned that can only be used to exchange for an access token by an authenticated client, i.e. the backend service